# Is it possible to scale up pods in expectance of high traffic in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, server, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

So, we are thinking about switching our production server to Kubernetes. Right now, it's not really professional as it's only one single nginx instance.
99% of the time our server needs to handle about 30 requests a minute, which it easily manages to do.
On **specific times, that we exactly know of in before**, there can be 2000 Users on the same second expecting a service. That is obviously way too much for it and last time it often returned a 502.
Kubernetes Autoscaling seems like a good approach for that. The only problem is that we need the extra containers at that specific time, not 30 seconds after.

So is there a way to "manually" scale? Like telling to Kubernetes to prepare 4 containers at exactly 8 PM MESZ e.g.?

Comment: Another approach is outlined in [this article (external link)](https://medium.com/symbl-ai-engineering-and-data-science/time-based-scaling-for-kubernetes-deployments-9ef7ada93eb7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of way to autoscale Pods in Kubernetes.

### Horizontal Pod Autoscaler

You can use an [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to scale up Pods reactively, based on metrics. You can also use custom metrics.

### Manually adjust number of replicas

You can also manually set the number of `replicas:` in the [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). This can be done *declaratively* by changing the manifest, or *imperatively* by using kubectl:

```
kubectl scale deployment my-app --replicas=5
```

### Use a CronJob to adjust the number of replicas

You can also use a Kubernetes [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) with a kubectl-image that does the command above to scale up number of replicas at a specific time.

### Use Knative Serving Autoscaler to autoscale per request

When using Knative Serving, you can use the [Knative Service Autoscaler](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/autoscaling/concurrency/) to scale up based on the number of requests.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a nice summary to start with